# How to substitute zero in place of variables in this query

Tags: mysql

I am calculating values (COST , Discount , SERVICE_CHARGE , SERVICE_TAX ) from the database directly  based upon its depeendent values

As part of this , i am dynamically forming SQL as shown below

This is my sql fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e72e7a/1

```
   SELECT @cst := cost AS cost , 
  @dis := discount_amount AS Discount ,
  @st := (service_tax/100*((@cst)-(@dis)+(@sc))) AS service_tax , 
  @sc := (service_charge/100*((@cst)-(@dis))) AS service_charge ,
  @vat := VAT AS VAT
    FROM Vendor_items
    WHERE vendor_items_id = 264
```

My question is  during calculation of service_tax , if the value of @sc is not yet computed ,  how to substitute zero (0) in place of @sc for the cacluation of service_tax .

Comment: You could decalare @sc as 0, if you are getting it as null use ISNULL function.

Comment: This is my sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e72e7a/3 , could you please tell me how to declare it as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

**Option 1:** Change the order of the way you select, so you get @sc before computing @st like below:

```
SELECT @cst := cost AS cost , 
@dis := discount_amount AS Discount ,
@sc := (service_charge/100*((@cst)-(@dis))) AS service_charge ,
@st := (service_tax/100*((@cst)-(@dis)+(@sc))) AS service_tax , 
@vat := VAT AS VAT
FROM Vendor_items
WHERE vendor_items_id = 264
```

**Option 2:** Use SET to set default value of 0 to @sc variable like below:

```
SET @sc = 0;
SELECT @cst := cost AS cost , 
@dis := Discount AS Discount ,
@st := (service_tax/100*((@cst)-(@dis)+(@sc))) AS service_tax , 
@sc := (service_charge/100*((@cst)-(@dis))) AS service_charge ,
@vat := VAT AS VAT
FROM Vendor_items
WHERE vendor_items_id = 264
```

Comment: I cannot change the order , i need to use option 2 only , Thank you very much .

Comment: No problem. If you think it helped, accept the answer and close this question.

Comment: How can i initialize all the variables to zero similarly as you initialized  @sc = 0 ; i tried this way , this is my http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e72e7a/31

Comment: Yes it worked for you no? Btw that's the follow up question as well but you did it. Great work..

Comment: No it didn't worked . Each set is being excuted seperately (Forming an update statement )

Comment: Am afraid, please raise a new question as this is a follow up question and close this one.